# Set null value with Cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to set a null value for a property when I create a node.

I tried something like this:

```
CREATE(p:Person {p_id: TOINT(line.`id`) })
SET p.initials = null
```

But that gives me `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError`.

How can I set a null value with CQL in Neo4j?

Comment: Show full query, which can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

In Neo4j you can't set null to property that way. But to get the same result you can remove the property for the given node. You can learn more about removing properties in [neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/remove/#remove-remove-a-property)